# Does JaxB Load Entire All data into into Memory before marshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, stax

I keep hearing around that JAXB is a slower XML marshaller/unmashaller. This is because it loads all data into memory at once. StaX has been suggested as an alternative because it is a streaming API which only loads the particular line you are currently working on into memory.

Seems to me that JAXB would only be slower when unmarshalling because you feed it an XML file to parse. Where as if you are mashalling XML the data is probably coming into your program outside of JAXB (assuming it wasn't originally XML) and thus JaxB has no control over how much data is loaded into memory.

Is this a correct assumption? I'm trying to get a clearer undestanding of how JAXB marshals XML and how difference it is compared to streaming APIs.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. JAXB marshalls objects that are *already* in memory, created by the application and passed to JSXB for marshalling. It doesn't load anything itself during marshalling. It creates objects during *unmarshalling.*

Answer (score 0):

Jaxb needs to keep all data in memory in order to resolve references.

When you have object A referenced by object B, what gets stored in the XML record of object B is the id of object A.  Therefore, the id of object A must be known at the time that object B is being saved. Since JAXB cannot foresee which objects are referenced by which, it needs to have them all in memory while saving.

The same thing holds true when loading: when JAXB loads the XML record of object B, it will find in it the id of object A. So, it will need to be able to find object A by id (in a map maintained internally by JAXB) so that it can store a reference to object A within the newly created object B.

So, yes, JAXB needs to keep everything in memory.

I do not know whether JAXB is smart enough to detect the case where you have no objects referencing one another so as to skip all of that stuff. But if you do not have objects referencing one another, then you probably do not need something as sophisticated as JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB doesn't load all the data *before* unmarshalling, but since it's supposed to create Java objects/values for all XML elements and attributes, it will end up loading all the data *during* unmarshalling.

Otherwise your object model would be incomplete.

Streaming APIs are good for reading large XML files, assuming *you* don't need all the information at the same time. If you can process the first part before continuing, you won't need to hold on to that data, and it can be freed, allowing reused of the memory.

---

The same goes for marshalling. JAXB requires that the entire object model is built in memory *before* marshalling. It isn't JAXB that "loads" the data, it just consumes it.

Streaming APIs are also good for writing large XML files, since it can be built incrementally.

Comment: You're describing *un*-marshalling.